# Can one add the output of a function in Python as a column to a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, apply, pycountry-convert

I have an array of countries. I would like to run this array through a function and append the output of the function as a column to a dataframe.

I used the `apply` method but keep getting a `KeyError`. I am not sure what I am doing wrong.

**Code**

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd
import pycountry_convert as pc

data - pd.read_csv('/content/2019.csv', index_col=0)
data.loc[71, 'Country or region'] = 'Trinidad and Tobago'

country_region = data['Country or region']

for country in country_region:
    country_code = pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2(country)
    data['Continent'].apply(pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code(country_code))
```

Here is [a screenshot of my error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fnG2h.png), for more details.

Comment: Please include your code _as [formatted](/help/formatting) text_, not as a screenshot

Comment: Thanks for the advice. I will do that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can use a function. You were almost there. If your function takes a single argument, and you are applying to a column, there's no need to add the argument. If you want to use multiple args, you can combine apply and lambda.

No need for lambda in your case, This should solve it:

```
data = pd.read_csv('/content/2019.csv', index_col=0)
data.loc[71, 'Country or region'] = 'Trinidad and Tobago'
data['country_code'] = data['Country or region'].apply(pc.country_name_to_country_alpha2)
data['Continent'] = data.country_code.apply(pc.country_alpha2_to_continent_code)
```

For future references, you can copy the code in your question instead of attaching a screenshot.